# How set set bash variable to file name in Docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I have a Dockerfile in which files in a directory are downloaded:

```
RUN wget https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~cesrulib/downloads/tarballs/ -r -l1 --no-parent -A tgz \
                                     --cut=99 -nH -nv --show-progress --progress=bar:force:noscroll
```

I know that there is exactly one file here of the form "bmad_dist_YYYY_MMDD.tgz" where "YYYY_MMDD" is a date. For example, the file might be named "bmad_dist_2020_0707.tgz". I want to set a bash variable to the file name without the ".tgz" extension. If this was outside of docker I could use:

```
FULLNAME=$(ls -1 bmad_dist_*.tgz)
BMADDIST="${FULLNAME%.*}"
```

So I tried in the dockerfile:

```
ENV FULLNAME $(ls -1 bmad_dist_*.tgz)
ENV BMADDIST "${FULLNAME%.*}"
```

But this does not work. Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: ENV is not bash. Use RUN instead

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer RUN does not work either. See the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Shell expansion does not happen in Dockerfile `ENV`. Then workaround that you can try is to pass the name during Docker build.

Grab the filename during build name and discard the file or you can try `--spider` for `wget` to just get the filename.

```
ARG FULLNAME
ENV FULLNAME=${FULLNAME}
```

Then pass the full name dynamically during build time.
For example

```
docker build --build-args FULLNAME=$(wget -nv https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Golden_Gate_Bridge_0002.jpg 2>&1 |cut -d\" -f2) -t my_image .
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ENV ... ...` syntax is mainly for plaintext content, docker build arguments, or other environment variables. It does not support a subshell like your example.

It is also not possible to use `RUN export ...` and have that variable defined in downstream image layers.

The best route may be to write the name to a file in the filesystem and read from that file instead of an environment variable. Or, if an environment variable is crucial, you could set an environment variable from the contents of that file in an `ENTRYPOINT` script.